# How to install CocoaPods needed for Google Sign-In Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to use Google Sign-In Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin provided at cordova community in ios. During installation on mac it ask for **CocoaPods pod file**.There is a doc to install google sdk with cocoa pods(https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods).But not able to run app with above plugin.

Comment: Can you link to the plugin you refer to?

Comment: Google Sign-In Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin [link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Google Sign-In SDK.
Did you check you create pod file in your project?
You can make pod file $ cd /project/pod install.
After then, add your dependencies like below

platform :ios, '8.1'
target "YourProjectNameHere" do
  pod 'Google'
end

and save them.
And open terminal and run $ pod update.
Open .xcworkspace file.

Comment: I getting  **linker command failed with exit code 1**  error stating 'Google/SignIn' cannot be found